# Show that $\liminf_{n \to \infty}A_n=\{\omega: \lim_{n \to \infty} 1_{A_n}(\omega)=1 \}$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Show that $\liminf_{n \to \infty}A_n=\{\omega: \lim_{n \to \infty} 1_{A_n}(\omega)=1 \}$.

Where $\liminf_{n \to \infty}A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}A_n$ and  indicator function is defined as 
\begin{align}
&1_{A_n}(\omega)=1 \text{ if } w\in A_n\\
&1_{A_n}(\omega)=0 \text{ if } w\notin A_n\\
\end{align}

I was trying to use another fact that
\begin{align}
\liminf_{n \to \infty}A_n=\{w:\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{A_n}(\omega)< \infty \}
\end{align}
but don't know how to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following statements are equivalent:

- $\omega\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_{k}$
- $\exists n\forall k\geq n\left[\omega\in A_{k}\right]$
- $\exists n\forall k\geq n\left[1_{A_{k}}\left(\omega\right)=1\right]$
- $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}1_{A_{n}}\left(\omega\right)=1$

Note that the fourth statement implies the third because characteristic functions only take the values $0,1$.

Comment: Could you explain what notation on the right hand side of 2 and 3 means?

Comment: @drhab: Sorry, didn't mean to usurp your post. My typing is awfully slow.

Comment: @copper.hat  Ego te absolvo :)

Comment: @Alex An integer $n$ *exists* ($\exists n$) such that for *all* integers $k\geq n$ ($\forall k\geq n$)....

Comment: thanks. If you guys want @copper.hat. I can change the accepted answer?

Comment: @Alex: If you don't mind, I would prefer if you did change to drhab. The answers are the same and he was first.

Comment: ok. no problem.

Comment: @Alex: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

$x \in \liminf_n A_n $ **iff** there exists some $n$ such that $x \in \cap_{k \ge n} A_k$ **iff** there exists some $n$ such that $x \in A_k$ for all $k \ge n$ **iff** there exists some $n$ such that $1_{A_k}(x) = 1$ for all $k \ge n$
**iff** $\lim_n 1_{A_n}(x) = 1$.

The 'if' part of the last equivalence uses the fact that the indicator function is integer valued.